# Searching for time series inside another time series

Tags: time-series, clustering

I have a time series "A" and another one "B". I would like to find occurrences of "B" inside "A". Typically, "A" is much bigger (magnitude: millions of points) than "B" (magnitude: hundreds of points)

- I don't necessarily want exact matching (obviously, since the values we deal are real numbers not, say, text) The values are preferably close, though.
- Trends/shapes are more important than exact time matching (i.e. somehow Dynamic Time Warping could be useful)
- With regards to the first two points, what happens if I don't care about the absolute values at all but just the shape (maybe taking a log of the values?)
- What happens if I would like to scale the number of points to billions from millions? How to scale the system? How do I index a time series? (maybe use Mahout, Lucene, somehow?)

What's inside above parentheses are the results of my short research, not necessarilly correct. All in all, what kind of an approach should I take? What are your general suggestions/tips? I'd like to develop a system, so any practical examples/suggestions are even more welcome.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you provide a simple example w/ data for time-series A & B that would demonstrate what you mean?

Comment: A clear and quantitative description of what it would mean for $A$ to be "close" to a subsequence of $B$ is essential. For some meanings--for instance, where "close" means strongly correlated--there are extremely efficient and effective solutions. For other meanings the problem will be impossible to solve without an exhaustive search.

Comment: Let's assume we're talking about temperature values: from -100 to 1000 celcius, real numbers.

Comment: That does not clarify what it means for two *time series* of values to be "close".  Although the question refers to "the shape," this could mean many things, especially in light of the mysterious reference to "absolute values" (which, although that has a well-defined mathematical meaning, does not seem to be what you wanted to say).

Answer (score 2):

Such a shorter series is known as **motif**. Think of music: a motif is a subsequence that appears at multiple times, and even in different compositions.

With [Time Series Motifs](http://scholar.google.com/scholar?q=Time%20Series%20Motifs) you will find plenty of literature.